# Do I need Google Play Licensing?

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have an app that I want to market on google Play.  Initially I want to charge a fixed price for the app.

I'm used to marketing apps on the Windows Phone Marketplace where a user simply has to pay to get the app - no "licensing" is necessary because the user can't get the app without paying for it.

I read the material about Google Play licensing and it seems to imply that unless I use the LVL, users can get ahold of my app for free. Is that right? On the other hand, if Google Play won't let them have the app without paying, why do I need to use licensing?

Comment: "I read the material about Google Play licensing and it seems to imply that unless I use the LVL, users can get ahold of my app for free".  Where did you read this?  Complete nonsense.

Comment: @Simon It's true in a way. While Google Play won't provide it, it's certainly not impossible for users to get a hold of many apps for free.

Comment: Within the context of the OP, it's the same for all platforms.  LVL won't stop someone stealing your app.

Comment: This is a business question - off-topic for SO.

Comment: "a business question?"  deployment is part of the development process and this is a key part of deployment.

Comment: Its not impossible for a paid app to be available for free if licensing is not used. A person who downloads the app, who may have a rooted phone, create a copy of the APK that is stored on the device and redistribute using third party stores or file sharing websites.

Comment: What about an app that is free to download but requires in-app purchase to unlock features?  It seems that this type of model might not require the licensing support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) say, this is really to

> verify that the current user did in fact pay for the application on Google Play

This is to combat piracy. Google Play won't give them the app without paying, but they might obtain the app from another source without paying and install it manually. This provides a runtime check.

Comment: other than stealing off my dev box, how would the "obtain the app from another source??

Comment: Person A could legitimately purchase the APK from Google Play, then copy the file to their computer and publish it on a website. Person B would then download the APK and install to their device.

Comment: oh my!  I didn't know they could do that makes Google Play Licensing a must.  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Don't assume that just because you add LVL that you're safe though. It's a complicated topic. See: http://www.digipom.com/how-the-android-license-verification-library-is-lulling-you-into-a-false-sense-of-security/

Comment: so for free apps this is useless?

Comment: @lxknvlk as for now, the LVL library is useful also for free apps, as stated in the documentation